# Custom query when using jamierumbelow/codeigniter-base-model

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I'm using https://github.com/jamierumbelow/codeigniter-base-model in my project.  But I've got a problem.

I need to make a query like:

```
SELECT * 
FROM words 
JOIN antonym ON words.antonym_id = antonym.id 
WHERE words.keyword COLLATE utf8_bin = 'xxxxx'
```

I have 2 models: `words` & `antonym`

And tried:

```
$this->words->with("anatomy")->get_many_by("keyword COLLATE utf8_bin", 'xxxxx')
```

But it threw an error, query string become:

```
SELECT * 
FROM words 
JOIN antonym ON words.antonym_id = antonym.id 
WHERE 'words.keyword' 'COLLATE' 'utf8_bin' = 'xxxxx'
```

What should I do in this case? Do I need to make a new direct query like:

```
$this->db->query("SELECT * from words JOIN antonym ON words.antonym_id = antonym.id WHERE words.keyword COLLATE utf8_bin = 'xxxxx'")
```

I will appreciate your help.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In such custom queries better to write your own query. Your solution is proper one.

```
$this->db->query("SELECT * from words JOIN antonym ON words.antonym_id = antonym.id WHERE words.keyword COLLATE utf8_bin = 'xxxxx'")
```

Comment: @user2411800 are you expecting another answer?